# Как получить адреса XHR-запросов произвольной страницы?

Tags: php, xhr

Каким образом с помощью PHP можно получить адреса XHR-запросов произвольной страницы по ссылке `$url`? Эти же запросы в инспекторе Chrome:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: опишите задачу в целом. В общем случае, у вас это вряд ли получится. Частности можно распарсить. Для особо упоротых вэб-браузер через COM, и надежда на существование API логгирования сетевой активности.

Comment: @teran Например, средствами PHP узнать, какие запросы посылает JS при загрузке страницы.

Comment: чья страница то? произвольная (с любого другого сайта по заданной `url`) или ваша (страница вашего сайта)?

Comment: @teran В том и дело, что произвольная.

Comment: а в чем цель этого действа вообще?

Comment: @teran Конкретной цели нет, но есть возможное применение. К примеру, определять, куда страница отправляет пользовательские данные (те же счётчики поисковых систем и т.п.). Понимаю, пример нелепый, но это лишь пример.

Comment: изучайте [этот список](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814757/headless-internet-browser/814929#814929) и им подобные. ищите у кого есть API для отслеживания всех потоков.

Comment: очевидно, что для этого страницу в _браузере_ надо загрузить и выполнить. Просто посмотрев на текст страницы, вы не узнаете конечные адреса запросов. и отправляются ли они вообще. В принципе и при загрузке страницы в браузере и выполнении, вам надо будет знать все нюансы, при каких событиях может отправляться xhr запрос.

Comment: @teran Спасибо за ответы!